# Why am I getting no warning when writing = instead of ==?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Struggled during hours to finally identify a bug due to this invalid statement:

```
...
assert( variable = -0.5 );
```

This should obviously be `assert( variable == -0.5 );`: developer typo.

I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2015, and really work on having a "0-warning compilation".

How could such a bad and dangerous statement compile with no warning being reported by the compiler? Is there no compiler option we can enable to avoid this?

**Edit**: Even `bool b = ( variable = -0.5 )` does not produce any compiler warning

Comment: What warning level are you using?

Comment: Are you using level 4 of compiler warnings?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Default (/W3), /Wall does not issue any warning neither.

Comment: Are your asserts enabled? If they're disabled, the preprocessor gets rid of `variable = -0.5` entirely before the compiler gets a chance to warn.

Comment: Code like this `-0.5 = variable` and you get your warning

Comment: @hvd: Even `bool b = ( variable = -0.5 )` does not produce any warning...

Comment: @jpo38  Check compiler options. I think there is some level of warning that can be set for such cases.

Comment: @Blobonat *Code like this `-0.5 = variable` and you get your warning*  I'd hope my compiler gives me an actual error on that and not just a warning...  ;-)

Comment: Another nice example where using a Yoda-Condition would have saved (a lot of?) time. :-)

Comment: @alk Also, the use of peer review would have been very likely to find the problem.

Comment: assert is macro. It is disabled if, at the moment of including <assert.h>, a macro with the name NDEBUG has already been defined. 

Can it be your case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignments within conditional expressions are only warned against if you are using `/W4` compilation level, see [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he.aspx).

So I tested it using an online MSVC compiler (I don't have VS 2015 on this PC) on this code:

```
//Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
int main(){
    int a;
    if (a = 2){
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    }
    assert(a = 3);
}
```

And this command line: `source_file.cpp -o a.exe /EHsc /MD /W4 /I C:\boost_1_60_0 /link /LIBPATH:C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib` and both lines warned:

```
Warning(s):
source_file.cpp(9) : warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression
source_file.cpp(12) : warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression
```

---

Apparently a QT header `qglobal.h` disables this warning using `QT_WARNING_DISABLE_MSVC(4706)` under certain configurations.

Comment: @Xarn: as commented in the OP, no warning even with /W4 (could be a bug in VS...)

Comment: @jpo38 And are you compiling in Debug? Or rather with asserts enabled? The other option is that the assert is not transparent enough for the compiler to see that the assignment is inside conditional expression.

Comment: @jpo38: I doubt this is a VS bug. If you've set warnings to max and you're still not getting one, then you should look into Project Properties > C\C++ > Advanced > Disable Specific Warnings to see if someone disabled that warning.

Comment: @Xarn: As commented on other answers, even `bool b = ( refSlope = -0.5 );` produces no warning. So `assert` is not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @jpo38 And do you really have `/W4` enabled? In comments you only specify `/W3`. Because I just tested this and see the answer (in a minute).

Comment: @Xarn: I was in /W3, but moved to /W4 and even /Wall for testing and it does not issue the warning (I'm compiling from the GUI)

Comment: @jpo38: Additionally (assuming you have debug turned on), the `assert` could be hidden within a template that is never instantiated.

Comment: @jpo38 At this point we are going to need a minimal reproducible example consisting of your build file and a source file that has the bug and doesn't trigger the warning.

Comment: @Xarn: Created a new project from scratch with your example and this does trigger the warning in level4. There must be a file I include who disables the warning, I'll investigate that.

Comment: @Xarn: Got it. My code includes QFile from Qt, and qglobal.h does `QT_WARNING_DISABLE_MSVC(4706)` which disables the waning for good...

Comment: @jpo38 Ouch. Gonna put it into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're not getting a warning because it's a completely legal and used expression, e.g.,

```
while( (char c = getNextChar()) ) ...
```

Some people therefore, when comparing to a const, tend to write the const on the lhs:

```
assert( -0.5 =  variable ); // this is an error
assert( -0.5 == variable ); // this is correct
```

Note that this does not scale to when you have two non-consts to compare; also, it's arguable whether remembering this rule is any easier to remembering `==` vs. `=`.

Comment: "*remembering*" it's a matter of discipline and training as mostly ... ;-)

Comment: @alk: well.. amongst the things I never understand is why we couldn't keep `:=` or even `<-` as set-equals and keep `=` as is-equals. I use it, I live with it - and whenever I talk to non-programmers, I tell the usual excuses. Why was `=` preferred as set-equals in K&R C, apart from confusing math&phys people?

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate fact is that there is no easy way to avoid this kind of error via static time analysis.  Consider this:

```
assert(var = possiblyUnsafeOp());
assert(var.otherOp() == something);
```

The first line proves that possiblyUnsafeOp() returns a non-null and cannot be called an error in writing the test.

Comment: This is a horrible idea, because asserts are noop in release builds.

Comment: Yes, it is horrible code.  However, it was only meant to illustrate what someone might do to prevent practical warning systems from catching things.

Answer (score 0):

You have no warnings because the assert tests the assignment, and it works. 
As blobonat said a safer code would be : `-0.5 = variable`

Comment: assert is not the root cause of the problem. Even `bool b = ( refSlope = -0.5 );` produces no warning.

Comment: Yes, I talk about the assert because it is what is used in his code. The affectation in the assert is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That pattern is useful for going through a list until 0 is found, so people might write that on purpose, this is why no warning is generated. For example:

```
while(int a = nextElem()){
  //Do something with a
}
```

instead of:

```
int a = nextElem();
while(a){
  //Do something with a
  a = nextElem();
}
```

Or to do something only if a function returned non-0 which usually means an error

```
if(int res = myFunction()){
  //Do something only if non-0
}
```

In your case variable was being assigned -0.5 and when that was casted to the int that an assert expects it was clamped to 0. You can avoid this by changing the positions of the check, because `-0.5 = variable` is not valid (but `-0.5 == variable` is), so it wouldn't compile unless you've putted the two = signs.

Answer (score -2):

This behavior can come in handy actually, what if you want to evaluate some complex statement using assert but you have to do some assignments beforehand? in this case (can't think of a valid example right now, but i do remember using it this way) you can do:

```
assert(variable = -0.5, (do something with variable));
```

This cannot be used in the release version obviously but can be helpful with complex asserts.

Comment: This is a horrible idea, because asserts are noop in release builds.

Comment: why all the vote downs? i didn't say you should use it in release, you can use it to make complex asserts, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @monkeyStix Just like the other two deleted answers, this misses the point of the question: Given compilers warn about stuff like `if (i = 0)`, why don't they warn about the way dodgier `assert(i = 0)` too?

Comment: @Baum mit Augen although i don't like it myself, for some people making assignments in if's and while's is common practice, i was merely explaining why the default behavior is to not warn the user.